# Ubuntu 16.04: Chrome login expires after every roboot

Tags: 16.04, login, google-chrome

I am using HP Precision 3510 with Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (installed recently).
After installing I faced issues while installing chrome. I installed it using: `sudo apt-get install -f` then it installed the missing dependencies (got this idea from another questions). With this Chrome installed successfully but it comes with weird behavior.

After login into chrome browser to sync my bookmarks and other data, when I reboot my machine, chrome expires the login and ask me to login again.

[image: Asking for login again !]

Previously with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS this issue wasn't there. Any idea what is wrong here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, finally I was able to find the issue. It was all because of keyring authentication. everytime I was starting Chrome, a keyring popup used to display and ask for password, but till then chrome has already initialized. After I reset the keyring password to blank, this issue got resolved. may be setting a blank password in keyring is not a good idea, but for time being it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your Google account has 2-step verification enabled, and it's messing up with your app login? Is it the same when you're just restarting Chrome? Or does it happens only when you reboot?

Comment: It happens only when I am reooting

Comment: Do you have Google 2-step verification enabled with your account?

Comment: yes i have.. but chrome did asked me for verification code, i provided it as well. but still

Comment: In Ubuntu, I'm using Chromium not Google Chrome. Perhaps you could try to ask about your problem in here : https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/chrome I think it is more apt for that forum.

Comment: May be you are right. Only thing I am not able to understand, Why Chrome behaving differently on my laptop but working just fine in my desktop (both of them running on Ubuntu 16.04)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of resetting the keyring password to blank, you can also **disable auto login** when your Ubuntu starts in your system settings. I tested it on my machine and it resolved the issue.